# PowerShell - Creating Top Link Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, top-link-bar

I am able to create a dropdown menu in SharePoint Online using the script below. The results is in the first image, is it possible to create the 2nd image using PowerShell also?

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
     
    #Add a Link to Top Navigation Bar
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Support Center" -Url "http://support.crescent.com" -Location TopNavigationBar
 
    #Get the Navigation node "Support Center"
    $ParentID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq "Support Center"}  | Select -ExpandProperty ID
    #Add a link under "Support Center
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Application Support" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/apps" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ParentID
  
    Write-host "Quick Launch Links Added Successfully!" -f Green
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Edit: Attempt

[image]

```
 #Add a Link to Top Navigation Bar
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Support Center" -Url "http://support.crescent.com" -Location TopNavigationBar
 
    #Get the Navigation node "Support Center"
    $ParentID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq "Support Center"}  | Select -ExpandProperty ID
    

    #Add a link under "Support Center
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Application Support" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/apps" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ParentID


   #Get the Navigation node "Application Support"
    $AppSupportID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq "Application Support"}  | Select -ExpandProperty ID

    #Add a link under "Application Support"
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Test" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/<test-url>" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $AppSupportID
```

[image]

Comment: Did you tried adding one more `Add-PnPNavigationNode` command for "Test" navigation link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
#Parameters
$SiteUrl = "<SiteURL>"
$Username = "<Admin>"
$Password = "<Password>"

$ParentTitle = "1"
$ParentURL = "<Link1>"
$ChildTitle = "2"
$ChildURL = "<Link2>"
$SubChildTitle = "3"
$SubChildURL = "<Link3>"

#Connect to PnP Online
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credential $cred

#Add a Link to Top Navigation Bar
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $ParentTitle -Url $ParentURL -Location TopNavigationBar

#Get the Parent Navigation node
$ParentID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq $ParentTitle}  | Select -ExpandProperty Id

#Add a Link under Parent link
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $ChildTitle -Url $ChildURL -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ParentID

#Get the Child Navigation node
$ChildID = (Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $ParentID).Children

#Add a link under Child link
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $SubChildTitle -Url $SubChildURL -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ChildID.Id
```

This works for one child/subchild link a time.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to add a second child link/sub child link to the existing nodes, just repeat the process and skip creating link on the top level:

```
#Parameters
$SiteUrl = "<SiteURL>"
$Username = "<Admin>"
$Password = "<Password>"

$ParentTitle = "1" #Exsting Parent Link
$ChildTitle = "4"
$ChildURL = "<Link4>"
$SubChildTitle = "5"
$SubChildURL = "<Link5>"

#Connect to PnP Online
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credential $cred

#Get the Parent Navigation node
$ParentID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq $ParentTitle}  | Select -ExpandProperty Id

#Add another Link under Parent link
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $ChildTitle -Url $ChildURL -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ParentID

#Get the current Child Navigation node
$ChildID = (Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $ParentID).Children | Where {$_.Title -eq $ChildTitle}

#Add another link under Child link
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $SubChildTitle -Url $SubChildURL -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ChildID.Id
```

Comment: Thanks Chelsea that worked!  What if I wanted to create another ChildTitle and SubChildTitle?  How would I edit the $ChildID so that it doesn't refer to the previous one?

#Get the Child Navigation node
$ChildID = (Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $ParentID).Children

Comment: @williswin Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more `Add-PnPNavigationNode` command for "Test" navigation link like below:

```
#Get the Navigation node "Application Support"
$AppSupportID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location TopNavigationBar | Where {$_.Title -eq "Application Support"}  | Select -ExpandProperty ID

#Add a link under "Application Support"
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Test" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/<test-url>" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $AppSupportID
```

Add this code after:

```
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Application Support" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/apps" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $ParentID
```

**Related Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Add-PnPNavigationNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpnavigationnode)
2. [Navigation options for SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online)

Comment: I attempted to do the follow above and it ended up creating another link out of the Support Center

Comment: Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Test" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/<test-url>" -Location TopNavigationBar -Parent $AppSupportID

If I enter an actualy ID at $AppSupportID, it will create it.  So it looks like it isn't getting the correct ID with the current $AppSuipportID.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: That one did not work unfortunately.